# How to remove leading digits and dot from character vector?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which only has one column. In that column there are two types of data:

1. only character
2. "number.character"

I want to find the second type of data and delete the number and the dot.
I first convert the data from factors to characters. Then I used 'strsplit' to split the second type of data, but it did not work.

An example of my data:

```
df <- data.frame(Col1 = c("ab","12.cd","cc","dd","34.af"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I want to find `"12.cd"` and `"34.af"` and turn into `"cd"` and `"af"`

Could anyone please kindly solve this?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output.  Try with `sub("^[0-9]+\\.", "", df1$yourcolumn)`

Comment: okay! thanks for reminding! 
"ab","12.cd","cc","dd","34.af"
I want to find"12.cd" and "34.af"  and turn into"cd" and "af"
thank you !!

Answer (score 3):

We can match one or more numbers (`[^0-9]+`) followed by a `.` from the start (`^`) of the string and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
df$Col1 <- sub("^[0-9]+\\.", "", df$Col1)
df$Col1
#[1] "ab" "cd" "cc" "dd" "af"
```

Or another option is to match all non alphabetic characters and replace with blank

```
sub("[^[:alpha:]]+", "", df$Col1)
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(Col1 = c("ab","12.cd","cc","dd","34.af"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```